# In highcharts,series without dynamic data does not shift

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the combination of series with and without dynamic data,the series with dynamic data can be easily shifted but where as the other series which are not dynamic do not get shifted out completely.

I have reproduced the issue in the following link: https://jsfiddle.net/8uxepk21/
Here as you can see there are two series. The series with static data appears to be shifting but if you increase the size of the rang-selector,then the series with static data do not get shifted out of the chart completely but still stays unlike the other series.
Is there any option to shift data explicitly without using `series.addpoint()` method.
I have used `series.data[0].remove()` and it obviously works fine but when a new data has to arrive for the same series after some time,this remove() method would remove the arriving point aswell. Further if I provide any condition for the maximum points to be in series while shifting,even then it will cause performance issue.

***EXPECTED RESULT***: Both the series data have to be shifted completely irrespective of the data being static or dynamic.

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series1 = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 2000);
                var series2 = this.series[1];
                //setInterval(function () {
                    //var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                       // y = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
                    //series2.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                //}, 2000);
            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        animation: {duration: 100},
                        enableMouseTracking: true,
                        stickyTracking: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

tooltip:{
        shared: true,
                split: false,
         stickyTracking: true,
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                enabled: true,
                followPointer: true,
                followTouchMove: true,
          formatter: function(){
                var tooltip = "";
                var phaseNameList = "";
                
                //tooltip += "<b>I-unit "+ "<br/>"+ "x: "+this.x +"</b>";
                tooltip += "<b>I-unit "+ "<br/>"+ "x: "+ new Date(this.x)+
                "</b>";
                tooltip +=  "<br/>"+ "y: "+this.y +"</b>";
                tooltip +=  "<br/>"+ this + "</b>";
                return tooltip;
               }
},

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data1',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -90; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    },
    {
    name: 'Random data2',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -90; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 50)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve it you can add points with `null` values to the second series. Check the code and demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          series1 = chart.series[0],
          series2 = chart.series[1],
          x, y;

        setInterval(function() {
          x = (new Date()).getTime();
          y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
          series1.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
          series2.addPoint([x, null], false, true);

          chart.redraw();
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6vp5cbt8/

Comment: thanks for that. Although it will work completely fine but is there any way where in we can use interval of the graph but not the number of points to be the condition to shift?. I have come across the setextreme method of the highcharts but is there any other way?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. Could you explain to me more precisely what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually by your method,since you are adding null points to the series, whenever the respective series legend is disabled,then x-axis values are also plotted which is not as expected. Whenever legend is disabled,x-axis values should no be plotted aswell. Can you suggest something here?

Comment: Hi @Wojciech Chmiel,could you please check this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052823/aligning-the-xaxis-of-highcharts