# Aligning the xAxis of highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/hjzeo6u2/

In the above Link I have reproduced an issue where I wanted to align the X-Axis labels just below the respective series plots. As of now both the X-Axes labels are at the bottom of the complete plot of both the series which is not expected.

**I have tried with the `align` property of `xAxis` in from highcharts api reference** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.align
but could not find the expected solution.

The expected result should be that each X-Axis has to be just below its corresponding plot. Just like a series plot and then its X-Axis after that another series plot and then its X-Axis. Also as and when I resize the Y-Axis using the separator in between the plots,the X-Axis also should reposition itself accordingly.

Comment: As I understood - you would you like to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L3ruq4ds/ , am I right?

Comment: Thank you @SebastianWędzel for your reply but,is it possible to move the X-Axis of the first series dynamically whenever I resize Y-Axis using separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to achieve something like this? [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/va3rnp85/1/)

```
chart: {
  events: {
    render() {
      let chart = this,
        xAxis = chart.xAxis,
        controlLine = chart.yAxis[0].resizer.controlLine;

      xAxis[1].axisGroup.translate(0, -xAxis[1].axisGroup.getBBox().y + controlLine.getBBox().y)
      xAxis[1].labelGroup.translate(0, -xAxis[1].axisGroup.getBBox().y + controlLine.getBBox().y)
    }
  }
},
```